# Sequential workflow for retrieving list items

Tags: visual-studio-2012

How can i get the list items in sequential workflow on visual studio?

Note: list is also created on visual studio in the same project.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. This works:

```
SPWeb web=workflowProperties.Web;
SPList customwflist= workflowProperties.List;
string str="abcdeneme";
SPListItem listitem=workflowProperties.Item;
listitem["Address"]=str;
listitem.Update();
```